# Why is the conditional expectation $E[x|y]$ a function of the conditioning argument $y$? How about the pdf $p(x|y)$?

Tags: functions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

For a random variable $x$ and $y$, consider the conditional pdf $p(x|y)$ and the conditional expectation $E[x|y]$.

I previously thought that the conditional pdf or conditional expectation were functions of $x$, not $y$.

But I read that the $E[x|y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot p(x|y)dx$ is a function of $y$. Hence, when taking the expectation again on $E[x|y]$, we write:

$$
E[E[x|y]] = \int_{y = -\infty}^{\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot p(x|y)dx\right]p(y)dy.
$$

I do not understand this first because I thought $p(x|y)$ is a function of $x$, and therefore $E[x|y]$ also a function of $x$. Am I wrong in the first place?

Is $p(x|y)$ actually a function of $y$? Why isn't it a function of $x$?

Why isn't $E[x|y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot p(x|y)dx$ a function of $x$ when it clearly has $x$ in the expression? Is it a function of both $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x|y)dx$$

is clearly a function of $y$ because $x$ is integrated

For the same reason

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx= E(X)$$

is a constant...when the integral exists

---

$p(x|y)$ is surely a function of $y$ but it can also be a function of both $x,y$, i.e.

$$f(x|y)=y e ^{-xy}$$

$x>0$; $y \sim  U[1;2]$

Which is a Negative exponential density with a parameter that is uniformly distributed in $[1;2]$

Comment: Oh okay, so is this because the definition of expectation is a "definite" integral, actually evaluating $x$ at negative and positive infinity, that's making it the function of $y$?

Comment: @js9:   yes, right! As an exercise you can calculate $E(X|Y=y)$ for the neg exp density I showed in my answer and realize that the expectation is a function of $y$

Comment: Is there an instance when $p(x|y)$ is "only" a function of $y$? I can think of $p(x|y)$ being only a function of $x$, for example, when $x$ and $y$ are independent, however, not the other case since $p(x|y) = \frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)}$.

Comment: @js9 : Here it is! $f(x|y)=\frac{1}{y}$; $x \in (0;y)$...$X$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $(0;y)$ and $Y$ can be another rv...or simply a parameter

Comment: @js9 : it is the indicator function. I edited the comment avoiding it...it was just to say that $x \in (0;y)$

Comment: Thank you so much, many things are clearer now! Is it possible to interpret the example you gave, $f(x|y) = \frac{1}{y}$ in terms of the $p(x,y)$ and $p(y)$? Is $p(y) = y$ and $p(x,y) = 1$ in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of conditional density is f(x|y) = f(x $\cap$ y)/f(y).  Plus it is right in the name: the probability density depends on the condition, the value of y, so it has to be a function of y.  p(x|y) is generally a function of both x and y. If you integrate it over all y then you end up with a function that depends on x, called the marginal probability, f(x).  E[x|y] is not a function of x because it is an expectation--when you integrate over a variable between constant limits, the variable goes away.  It still depends on y though.  E[x|y] says "the average value of x given this value of y."
When you do a double integral to get a number, the outer integral has to have numbers for limits, but the inner integral can have functions of the outer variable for limits, because it will still be a function of the outer variable once you have done the inner integral, but it won't be a function of the inner variable any more because you "totaled it all up."  It can't depend on a specific value of inner variable because it already is built out of ALL the values of the inner variable.  Try writing out a couple of easy double integrals for yourself; find the area of a triangle, for example.  Watch when you have functions of what, and integrate in both orders so you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to interpret the example you gave in terms of the p(x,y) and p(y)?

Of course it is! There are several possible interpretation. Here is one...

$$f(x|y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}=\frac{2}{2y}$$

where

$$f(x,y)=2$$

is the joint uniform distribution on the following triangle

[image]

and $f(y)=2y$ is the density of the variable $Y$ where $y \in (0;1)$